# Merge "ngram" and "n-gram" tags

Tags: support, synonym-request

Currently both the tags [n-gram](/questions/tagged/n-gram) and [ngram](/questions/tagged/ngram) exist with close to equal numbers of questions but the former being a bit more popular.

Since I don't have enough rep to suggest this through the tag system and it's obviously just a spelling/hyphenation difference would somebody like to make the two synonyms please?

Comment: "n-gram" is probably more correct, so "ngram" should be the synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a long while before a synonym gets added/approved.  So, in the mean time, I retagged all [ngram](/questions/tagged/ngram) questions as [n-gram](/questions/tagged/n-gram).

As I understand it, after the cache clears in a day or 2, this will at least stop low-rep users from using ***ngram*** as a tag.