# Synonym proposal: [.deb] -> [deb]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I hope this is the correct place to ask for a new tag synonym for Stack Overflow.

I discovered this a few days ago and expected to be able to fix it myself when I reached the mythical 2,500 reputation, but alas, there are apparently additional constraints.

- [.deb](/questions/tagged/.deb) has 7 questions ever, 4 this year, 2 subscribers, top user 8 score; no wiki description.
- [deb](/questions/tagged/deb) has 44 questions ever, 33 this year, top user 10 score.

I also note the general pattern; there are many synonym mappings of the form [.ext] -> [ext]; perhaps this should be automated, or at least audited systematically.

I was hoping there would be a way for a low-reputation user to propose a synonym and have it vetted by a moderator, perhaps even as a mechanism to improve one's score. Surely this could not be the loophole the spammers have been waiting for.

Comment: As implicitly suggested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100864/merge-ngram-and-n-gram-tags I went ahead and changed all occurrences of [.deb] to [deb] for now.  There was a migrated question which I couldn't get at, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took care of this, the last stray [.deb](/questions/tagged/.deb) tags were merged into [deb](/questions/tagged/deb) and a synonym was created. As a long time Debian user and programmer, I can't think of a case where `.deb` doesn't mean `deb`.

As far as how to get it done, those who have the ability to edit tags can quickly fix small scale obviously problem tags (e.g [pyton](/questions/tagged/pyton) -> [python](/questions/tagged/python)). If a change is less than trivial, however and the proposed problematic tag has more than a hand full of followers, the merge / synonym request really should be discussed here.

This lets us avoid mistakes like making [preprocessor](/questions/tagged/preprocessor) a synonym for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), since the community has a few days to vote for the idea.

If the community signs off on it and there's nothing obviously wrong with doing it, a moderator will get it done in just a few clicks.